# AS3 : Why use MouseEvent as function Param when Event works fine?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am always trying to improve my programming practices and this one habit of mine has gotten me thinking that maybe it isn't the best approach. When handling `MouseEvent` function calls I have a tendency to use `Event` over `MouseEvent` in the params.

**Example:**

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);

private function handleClick(e:Event):void
{
     trace(e.currentTarget.name + " was Clicked");
}
```

Is there some functionality or properties inside of `MouseEvent` unavailable in the `Event` class that would make using `MouseEvent` more of a necessity? The only reason I can think of on my own is to keep your events/functions params strongly-typed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't type the parameter as MouseEvent, you will just have to cast it as a MouseEvent to access properties that are specific to the MouseEvent subclass. For example:

This won't work:

```
private function handleClick(e:Event):void
{
     trace("altKey down: "+e.altKey);
}
```

But this will:

```
 private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
 {
     trace("altKey down: "+e.altKey);
 }
```

However so will this (not recommended though, see below):

```
 private function handleClick(e:Event):void
 {
     trace("altKey down: "+MouseEvent(e).altKey);
 }
```

Generally speaking, you want your listener parameter type to be only as general as is necessary, so that if your function is called with the wrong type of event, it fails in an obvious way.

Your example works because currentTarget is a property of the Event base class. But there is nothing stopping your handleClick from receiving and responding to an IOErrorEvent or KeyboardEvent, and doing something you don't expect without failing (e.g. if you accidentally set it up to listen to something other than a MouseEvent, which you would not do deliberately, but could happen if you copy-paste the addEventListener line of code and change the event type but forget to change the handler function... these things do happen).

Comment: No problem! I should probably also have noted that one other reason it's helpful to be as specific as you can with the typing, is that the AS3 compiler does not do any compile-time typechecking of your event handler arguments. This is true also for any case where you pass a function reference (like for a callback). If you have a type or argument count mismatch, it will be a runtime breakage. But the worst cases is still when it doesn't fail but it should... Also, when you use the correct type "MouseEvent", you'll benefit from your code editor autocomplete for all available properties.

Comment: Also, while your question is specifically about Event and its subclass MouseEvent, the underlying more general question is: when should I use a base class reference for an instance of one (or more) of its subclasses, and the answer to that question is not a quick one, but rather an explanation of polymorphism in general, from a book or the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 2):

this is a list of information available from an [Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#Event%28%29):

- type:String
- bubbles:Boolean
- cancelable:Boolean

this is a list of information available from a [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MouseEvent%28%29):

- type:String
- bubbles:Boolean
- cancelable:Boolean
- localX:Number
- localY:Number
- relatedObject:InteractiveObject
- ctrlKey:Boolean
- altKey:Boolean
- shiftKey:Boolean
- buttonDown:Boolean
- delta:int
- commandKey:Boolean
- controlKey:Boolean
- clickCount:int

as you can see, the *MouseEvent* contains much more specific data for the event than a generic *Event* object.

something like the following will fail:

```
private function mouseEventHandler(evt:Event):void
{
trace(evt.localX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MouseEvent objects contain information beyond what Event objects have. That is, MouseEvent inherits from Event. Using Event works in the sense that the event listener will be called, but if you need mouse-specific properties of the event then just using the base class won't work.

In other words the answer to this question is "yes":

> Is there some functionality or properties inside of MouseEvent unavailable in the Event class that would make using MouseEvent more of a necessity?

Adam's answer gives you an example scenario.